# Access VBScript variable within Javascript inside of an HTA

Tags: javascript, variables, vbscript, hta

I'm trying to access a variable in javascript that i set in vbscript all within one hta file:

```
<script type="vbscript">
    var globalVariable = test123
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var globalVariable = <%= globalVariable %>;
</script>
```

This doesn't populate the variable globalVariable with anything. I've also tried

```
var globalVariable = "<%= globalVariable %>";
```

This just populates the string within the quotes into the variable globalVariable.

I can't get the value '`test123`' set in the VBScript section to populate into a JS variable within the JS section.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your question, I've written an HTA containing the following code:

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
dim globalvariable
globalvariable = "test123"
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert(globalvariable);
</script>
```

and the value "test123" is displayed in the alert box.

Note the following differences with your code:

- vbs language syntax is different to js syntax;
- your js code  looks like asp code to me, rather than js;
- I got an error message using '' without 'text/' prefix;

Comment: Apologies for the syntax errors within the initial question. Within my actual code, I had the proper syntax. Your code here works perfectly. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Mixing languages in a .HTA App is easy, if you just follow the syntactical rules for each language (e.g. there is no "var" in VBScript).

```
<html>
 <head>
  <hta:application id = "mix"></hta>
  <script LANGUAGE="VBScript">
  Dim gsX : gsX = "global VBScript variable"
  </script>
  <script LANGUAGE="JScript">
  alert(gsX);
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Apologies for the syntax errors within the initial question. Within my actual code, I had the proper syntax. Your code here also works perfectly. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a DOM element like a hidden input field to communicate between VBScript and JS? If that works you can trigger a custom event when the value changes, and listen for that event on both sections.

I never used VBScript before so this may not be possible.